# Пытаюсь сделать ручку на обновление таблицы. Как я могу сделать это эффективнее при помощи sqlx и gin?

Tags: mysql, golang, golang-gin

```
type News struct {
    ID         string `json:"id"`
    Title      string `json:"title"`
    Content    string `json:"content"`
    Categories string `json:"categories"`
}

var list = []News{}

func getNews(c *gin.Context) {
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, list)
}

func updateNews(c *gin.Context) {

    dbType := os.Getenv("DB_TYPE")
    dbName := os.Getenv("DB_NAME")
    dbUser := os.Getenv("DB_USER")
    dbPasswd := os.Getenv("DB_PASSWD")
    dbHost := os.Getenv("DB_HOST")
    dbPort := os.Getenv("DB_PORT")
    
    
    db, err := sqlx.Open(dbType, dbUser+":"+dbPasswd+"@tcp("+dbHost+":"+dbPort+")/"+dbName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err, "Ошибка открытия подключения.")
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Установка максимального количества открытых соединений в пуле
    db.SetMaxOpenConns(10)

    // Установка максимального количества соединений, которые могут быть одновременно использованы
    db.SetMaxIdleConns(5)

    // Проверка подключения к базе данных
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err, " Не удалось подключиться к базе.")
    }

    // Выполнение запросов к базе данных
    
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT news.Id, news.Title, news.Content, group_concat(newscategories.CategoryId separator ', ') as categories FROM news left join newscategories on news.Id=newscategories.NewsId group by news.Id;")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        //success := false
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    // Обработка результатов запроса
    for rows.Next() {
        var id string
        var title string
        var content string
        var categories string
        err := rows.Scan(&id, &title, &content, &categories)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        nnews := News{ID: id, Title: title, Content: content, Categories: categories}
        list = append(list, nnews)
        fmt.Println(list)
    }
    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }*/

    id := c.Param("id")

    
    for i, a := range list {
        if a.ID == id {
            c.BindJSON(&a)
            list[i] = a
            nid := c.Query(a.ID)
            ntitle := c.Query(a.Title)
            ncont := c.Query(a.Content)
            ncatg := c.Query(a.Categories)

            db, err := sqlx.Open(dbType, dbUser+":"+dbPasswd+"@tcp("+dbHost+":"+dbPort+")/"+dbName)
            _, err = db.Exec("update news SET news.Id = ?, news.Title = ? , news.Content = ?, news.Categories = ? WHERE news.Id = ?;", nid, ntitle, ncont, ncatg, nid)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, a)
            return
        }
    }
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"message": "news not found"})
}
```

Comment: Критерий эффективности какой?

Comment: @u_mulder, да чтобы хотя бы работало )